# play with PHP GET

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone help me to play with GET urls for example I have a link like this:

```
?id=5&lang=1
```

So my question is how can I make this one:

```
?id=5,1
```

I don't want to show the `&lang`, only I want is that the `&lang` to replace with , "comma" can anyone help me?

Comment: why dont you use the $_POST ? session ? cookies ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite `?id=5,1` to `?id=5&lang=1` internally.

Otherwise, the value of `id` will be `5,1`. Your application would then need to know that `id` contains more than the `id`. It could then parse out the language from the id. However, this will become confusing when you introduce more parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have already built the URL in the way you have specified, you can break the id field based on the comma and extract the real id and lang field

```
$urlPieces = explode(",", $_GET['id']);
$id = $urlPieces[0];
$lang = $urlPieces[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You are able to do this, but it's not very clean, in terms of the proper `$_GET` variable values. The solution automatically type casts the values to integers:

```
sscanf($_GET['id'], '%d,%d', $id, $lang);
// $id   = int(5)
// $lang = int(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

Firstly, you could simply reformat the parameters when they arrive in your PHP program. With `?id=5,1`, you'll get a PHP `$_GET` array with `id` `'5,1'`. This you can simply split using the `explode()` function to get the two values you want.

The second solution is to use the Apache `mod_rewrite` feature, to modify the URL arguments before they arrive at PHP. For this, you'll need to understand regular expressions (regex), as mod_rewrite uses this for it's work. You should google 'mod_rewrite' and 'regex' to find out more.

However mod_rewrite is typically used to get rid of GET arguments entirely. For example the URLs of the questions on this site do not have any get arguments, but the server translates the arguments between the slashes into GET arguments. This is considered better practice than simply than changing how the arguments look, as it is more user-friendly and SEO friendly.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $id . ',' . $lang;
<a href="?<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Comment: I think @Nickol means he/she wants to be able to parse a URL like that (maybe)

Comment: @brendan: if it's that there are tons of duplicated for explode function